# How to insert element for the linked list

Tags: c++, algorithm, linked-list

//I do not know how to insert element, and output the whole list.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class IntElement 
{
public:
    class IntElement *next;
    int data;
bool insertInFront( IntElement** head, int data )
{
IntElement *newElem = new IntElement;
if( !newElem ) return false;
newElem->data = data;
*head = newElem;
return true;
}
bool insertElement(IntElement **head, int d)
{
    IntElement *newElem = new IntElement;
    newElem->data=d;
    newElem=*head;
    *head=newElem->next;
    return true;
}
void print(IntElement **head)
{
     if(*head!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<(*head)->data<<endl;
        *head=(*head)->next;
    }
}
} ;
int main()
{

    IntElement *T=new IntElement;
    T->insertInFront( &T,7);
    T->insertInFront(&T,9);
    T->insertInFront(&T,213);
    T->insertInFront(&T,33);
    T->insertElement(&T,123);
    T->print(&T);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using `std::list`.  See `std::list::push_back()`.  These are already tested for you.  You don't have to waste time creating your own linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Reread this carefully:

```
IntElement *newElem = new IntElement;
newElem->data=d;
newElem=*head;
*head=newElem->next;
return true;
```

I doubt that `newElem = *head;` is doing what you wanted.

Comment: Think about the order of things -- after you assign `*head` to `newElement`, do you have anything that still points to the new item you allocated?